# ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x' using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot pie chart using varible data.

Below is my code. both **Postive_percentage** and **topic** is the **list** whose data comes from other part of code and through various operations. I have posted the value of **Postive_percentage** and **topic** from the output.

I am new to python thats why i am not able to understand the issue. **Postive_percentage**,  **topic** and **colors** have 7 variables and still it is giving me this error.

```
#topic and Postive_percentage copied from output and was not manually inserted by me. 
    topic = ['VirginAmerica', 'UnitedAirline', 'SouthWestAirline', 'USAirline', 'AmericanAirline', 'SpiritAirline', 'DeltaAirline']
    Postive_percentage = [3.917525773195876, 10.0, 6.666666666666667, 10.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0]


sizes = Postive_percentage
    print(sizes)
    labels = str(topic)
   # makeitastring = ''.join(map(str, labels))
    print(labels)
    colors = ['yellowgreen', 'lightgreen', 'darkgreen', 'gold', 'red', 'lightsalmon', 'darkred']
    plt.pie(sizes, explode=None, labels=labels, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)   #line 240
    #plt.pie(sizes, labels, colors)
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

this is the error that is being generated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Aryana/Desktop/Sentimental-Analysis-on-Twitter-master/senti_twitter.py", line 248, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Aryana/Desktop/Sentimental-Analysis-on-Twitter-master/senti_twitter.py", line 240, in main
    plt.pie(sizes, explode=None, labels=labels, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
  File "C:\Users\Aryana\Desktop\Sentimental-Analysis-on-Twitter-master\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3338, in pie
    frame=frame, rotatelabels=rotatelabels, data=data)
  File "C:\Users\Aryana\Desktop\Sentimental-Analysis-on-Twitter-master\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1855, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aryana\Desktop\Sentimental-Analysis-on-Twitter-master\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 2858, in pie
    raise ValueError("'label' must be of length 'x'")
ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `str(..)` when assigning to labels.
If you want a copy and not just the reference, replace it with `list(..)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
topic = ['VirginAmerica', 'UnitedAirline', 'SouthWestAirline', 'USAirline', 'AmericanAirline', 'SpiritAirline', 'DeltaAirline']
Postive_percentage = [3.917525773195876, 10.0, 6.666666666666667, 10.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0]


sizes = Postive_percentage
print(sizes)
labels = list(topic)
# makeitastring = ''.join(map(str, labels))
print(labels)
colors = ['yellowgreen', 'lightgreen', 'darkgreen', 'gold', 'red', 'lightsalmon', 'darkred']
plt.pie(sizes, explode=None, labels=labels, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)   #line 240
#plt.pie(sizes, labels, colors)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Explanation:**
When using `str()` on a list, it makes the whole list as string, including the square-brackets. Therefore, when printing on console, you might have thought that this is a list, while it is just a long string..

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. You solved my problem. I did add list() to topic and sizes and got the output. Thank you very much once again.