# Matplotlib - piechart - ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a pie chart using matplotlib. I am using python 2.7. I am trying to recreate the example given  [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_features.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-pie-features-py) with inputs from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991633/valueerror-label-must-be-of-length-x-using-matplotlib) stackoverflow post. But, I keep running into errors.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

topic = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', \
     'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' \
     'J']
labels = list(topic)
sizes = [18.7, 18.4, 12.7, 8.5, 3.4, 2.4, 1.8, 1.7, 1.5, 30.9]
explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, 
autopct='%1.1f%%',
    shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal')  

plt.show()
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "occupation_pie.py", line 13, in <module>
shadow=True, startangle=90)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1867, in inner
return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 2867, in pie
    raise ValueError("'label' must be of length 'x'")
ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x'
```

How can I make my code work?

Comment: Your code works fine if you put the missing `,` after `'I'`. I am voting to close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it on purpose that you are missing a `,` in `topics`?

Try changing `topic = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', \
     'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' \
     'J']`

to

`topic = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']`

Comment: Answers which are based on a typo are typically posted as comments.