# Matplotlib issue match # of values to # of labels -- ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x'

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have a df called `high` that looks like this:

```
   white  black  asian  native  NH_PI  latin
0  10239  26907   1079     670     80   1101`
```

I'm trying to create a simple pie chart with matplotlib. I've looked at multiple examples and other SO pages like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991633/valueerror-label-must-be-of-length-x-using-matplotlib), but I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\Sustainability & Resilience\Food Policy\Interns\Lara Haase\data_exploration.py", line 62, in <module>
    plt.pie(sizes, explode=None, labels = high.columns, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3136, in pie
    frame=frame, data=data)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1819, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 2517, in pie
    raise ValueError("'label' must be of length 'x'")
ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x'`
```

I've tried multiple different ways to make sure the labels and values match up. There are 6 of each, but I can't understand why Python disagrees with me.

Here is one way I've tried:

```
plt.pie(high.values, explode=None, labels = high.columns, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
```

And another way:

```
labels = list(high.columns)
sizes = list(high.values)
plt.pie(sizes, explode=None, labels = labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)`
```

Also have tried with `.iloc`:

```
labels = list(high.columns)
sizes = high.loc[[0]]
print(labels)
print(sizes)
plt.pie(sizes, explode=None, labels = labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
```

But no matter what I've tried, I keep getting that same key error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand on @ScottBoston's post,

Plotting a pie chart from a data frame with one row is not possible unless you reshape the data into a single column or series.

An operation I typically use is `.stack()`,

```
df = df.stack()
```

`.stack()` is very similar to `.T`, but returns a series with the column names as a second index level. This is handy when you have multiple rows and want to retain the original indexing. The result of `df.stack()` is:

```
0  white     10239
   black     26907
   asian      1079
   native      670
   NH_PI        80
   latin      1101
dtype: int64
```

After I `stack()` a data frame, I typically assign a name to a series using:

```
df.name = 'Race'
```

Setting a name is not required, but helps when you are actually trying to plot the data using `pd.DataFrame.plot.pie`.

If the data frame `df` had more than one row of data, you could then plot pie charts for each row using `.groupby`

```
for name, group in df.groupby(level=0):
    group.index = group.index.droplevel(0)
    group.plot.pie(autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
```

Since the first level of the index only provides the positional index from the input data, I drop that level to make the labels on the plot appear as desired.

[image]

If you don't want to use pandas to make the pie chart, this worked for me:

```
plt.pie(df.squeeze().values, labels=df.columns.tolist(),autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
```

This attempt didn't work because `high.columns` is not list-like.

```
#attempt 1
plt.pie(high.values, explode=None, labels = high.columns, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
```

This attempt didn't work because `list(high.values)` returns a list with an array as the first element.

```
#attempt 2
labels = list(high.columns)
sizes = list(high.values)
plt.pie(sizes, explode=None, labels = labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
```

The last attempt didn't work because `high.loc[[0]]` returns a dataframe.  Matplotlib does not know parse a dataframe as an input.

```
labels = list(high.columns)
sizes = high.loc[[0]]
print(labels)
print(sizes)
plt.pie(sizes, explode=None, labels = labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, using pandas dataframe plot:

```
df.T.plot.pie(y=0, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140, figsize=(10,8), legend=False)
```

Output:

[image]